# Notepad++_text search of file names and content

Tags: notepad++, search

I have not figured out how to do a simple search from within Notepad++ for a text string in (either filename or content) for a set of ascii text files created with Notepad++.

As of now, the files are all in a single folder on a separate hard drive partition.  I want to do these searches from within notepad++ so I can edit the text file when I find it.  I can locate the file with WinExp.  Are there Notepad++ tutorials to watch?

I'm about to give up on this and go back to xYplorer with allows me to do boolean searches. However I like the text editor features of Notepad++; xYplorer does not have that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Search -> **Find in Files**, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>:

[image: Find In Files Dialog]

Fill in your search text in the 'Find What:' box, specify the Directory in the directory field or by clicking on the '...' Button to specify a directory, and click 'Find All'.

Once done, the search will provide you with a window within Notepad++ with the locations of each file along with line numbers and your highlighted search term. Note that unfortunately it will not automatically open the files for you.

However, You can also do a direct replace from this screen, if you fill in the 'Replace With:' field and click the 'Replace in Files' button. This will prompt you with a warning that the text change will take effect immediately, so be sure to double-check what you've entered and that it will only affect the files you want.

Comment: Note this will not search in the file names.